full convolution method for backpropagation
How to perform full convolution in tensorflow , this method is explained in this article .
the function tf.nn.conv3d has parametre padding which accepte two types "SAME"and "VALID" but there is not "FULL"
thanks .

We don't have access to the article you mentioned, but according to the
documentation, the Conv3D layer padding accepts two parameters: valid and
same.Please refer Conv3D
